# Custom Vim HTML syntax

Tags: html, syntax-highlighting, vim, vim-syntax-highlighting

I have a script that reads an HTML file and replaces occurrences of `~%foo%~` with a value set by Perl. Something like this:

```
<span class="~%classname%~">~%hi_mom%~</span>
```

Would produce something like this in the browser:

```
<span class="classyclass">Hello World</span>
```

Right so I want to use Vim syntax highlighting to distinguish the occurrences `~%foo%~` in the HTML. By default, the HTML syntax highlighting will make an HTML element's attribute values `Magenta` and I want the `~%foo%~` portion to be `DarkMagenta`. I'm on the right track because if I comment out the `tokenQuoted` lines (or token lines) I get the desired results but with both matches and highlights uncommented the token highlighting overrides the `tokenQuoted` highlighting.

```
syntax match token       containedin=ALLBUT,htmlString,htmlValue '\~%[^%]\+%\~'
syntax match tokenQuoted containedin=htmlString,htmlValue        '\~%[^%]\+%\~'
" tokenQuoted assumes htmlString/htmlValue (:highlight String) is Magenta
highlight token          term=none ctermfg=White       guifg=White
highlight tokenQuoted    term=none ctermfg=DarkMagenta guifg=DarkMagenta
```

The file I'm working in is sourced after the default `html.vim` is sourced via
`autocmd *.html ~/.vim/syntax/html.vim` in `.vimrc`.

Comment: I think you forgot to ask a question. What is the problem? What are you seeing? What would you like to see instead?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that `token` match is not being excluded from being contained in the `tokenQuoted` match. To get the desired results, i.e. highlighting quoted tokens different from non quoted tokens, use the following in your syntax file.

```
syntax match token       containedin=ALLBUT,htmlString,htmlValue,tokenQuoted '\~%[^%]\+%\~'
syntax match tokenQuoted containedin=htmlString,htmlValue        '\~%[^%]\+%\~'
highlight token          term=none ctermfg=White       guifg=White
highlight tokenQuoted    term=none ctermfg=DarkMagenta guifg=DarkMagenta
```

Or if it makes sense to use a syntax region rather than a match, replace the syntax match lines above with the following.

```
syntax region token       contained start=+\~%+ end=+%\~+ containedin=ALLBUT,htmlString,tokenQuoted
syntax region tokenQuoted contained start=+\~%+ end=+%\~+ containedin=htmlString
```

I guess I should also mention that when I was testing this I just created the file `~/.vim/syntax/html.vim` and added the above content. There was no need to add anything to my .vimrc file.