# HTML string vim syntax highlighting

Tags: html, vim

I've been trying to write a [swig](http://paularmstrong.github.io/swig/docs/) syntax highlight file for vim and I've run into a bit of an issue.

Everything is working okay so far but it's not highlighting inside of html strings. I've looked around and I'm using `containedin=htmlString` but it's still not highlighting. Also htmlLink is showing the strange grayish color.

I am using [this](http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Identify_the_syntax_highlighting_group_used_at_the_cursor) to see what syntax applies and it's saying htmlString and htmlLink as I expected.

[Here](https://gist.github.com/brettof86/5946127) is a gist of my .vim syntax file

here is a screenshot of what I'm seeing: [image]

I expect `<a href="{{ config.root}}...` etc to have the curly braces highlighted

I also read [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5267205/custom-vim-html-syntax?rq=1) and it didn't help me or I didn't understand it

Comment: I'm not clear on the connection between swig and html.  I use swig quite a bit, but html hasn't come into it for me.  What language are you generating code for?

Comment: You might be thinking of the wrong swig. This is an html template engine named swig, not "Simplified Wrapper Interface Generator". Check the link in the OP.

Comment: aha!  Hard to imagine someone would name another package swig, but there ya go.

Comment: Yeah imagine the stuff I've one through trying to Google lol.

Comment: ^ That's "gone through". Stupid phone.

Comment: I'm going to call my next project Java.... ;-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From what I see in your definition you have:

```
syn region swgInside start=/{(%|{)/ end=/(%|})}/ keepend transparent containedin=@htmlSwgContainer

syn match swgBrackets "{%\|%}\|{{\|}}" containedin=swgInside
```

However on the screenshot you've posted I don't see swgBrackets contained in the swgInside blocks (which I see two: `{% if ... %}` and `{% endif %}`).

I would propose revising swgBrackets constraints (maybe removing containedin?).
This might help: 
[Vim syntax files ... trying to undestand "contains"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1819006/vim-syntax-files-trying-to-undestand-contains)

Comment: That was it. This was my first vim syntax implementation and I wasn't thinking clearly I guess. I have since changed it and I'm working past this now. Thanks for the answer.